# SharePoint 2010 HTML 5 videotag on mobile doesn't work

Tags: 2010, mobile, video

I am unable to play html 5 videos on mobile from SharePoint site.

Are there any other open source video player for mobile, please suggest.

Comment: So the video works in the your browser? Does your smartphones browser support HTML5?